# How do you get Microsoft Access 2007 32bit to show 64bit ODBC Drivers on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, odbc, 64-bit, ms-access-2007

I followed the advice here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing

but it does not apply.

I have Oracle drivers that are 64bit.  If I click the ODBC mmc in my admin tools I can see the DSN.  In my properties of the ODBC administrator, it appears to be pointing to the 64bit version of the ODBC administrator, which is good:

```
%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe
```

If I use this version of the ODBC administrator, I can see the Oracle drivers and my DSN via the mmc.  When I go to Microsoft Access 2007 (32bit), however, and click external data, ODBC, my 32bit ODBC administrator is opening, which does not have the driver.

Can Access 2007 32bit use a 64bit driver to connect to a database (oracle in this case)?  The driver works fine in all other applications, just not Access.  How can I get Access to use the 64bit ODBC administrator?

EDIT:

For clarification, the problem is that Access is opening the 32bit version, the syswow64 version.  I need it to open the native 64bit version, which it is not opening.  The problem is that Microsoft Access keeps opening the 32bit version.  I need it to open the 64bit version.  The MMC of the ODBC administrator is pointing to the 64bit version, but Microsoft Access keeps opening the 32bit version.  I need it to open the 64bit version.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Win7 has **TWO** odbcad32.exe executables. The one in system32, is, of all moronic things, actually the 64bit interface.

For real 32bit ODBC setups, you need to use the c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe

You can throw a tomato at Bill Gates next time you see him, and thank him on behalf of the entire planetary population for such a moronic design decision. He may not be in charge of M$ anymore, but it's still his fault... everything Windows is his fault.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear, sorry.  Access is opening the 32bit.  I need it to open the 64bit.  I cannot get it to open the 64bit.  How do I set it?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you on a 64bit Access? the 32bit version won't open the 64bit control panel, because any odbc connections you create in the 64bit panel will be useless/invisible to 32bit apps.

Comment: I guess that answers it.  Access 32bit cannot use 64bit drivers.  Thanks.